# The frame buffer layout of the current display cannot be made to match

Tags: windows, vmware

I get this error when I have VM running in VMWare Workstation on my work PC and try Remote Desktop-ing in from my iMac at home. I just upgraded VMWare Workstation to 7.0 from 6.0 and now I'm getting it when I try to resume my VM at work.

It then asks me the scary question of whether I want to preserve or discard the suspended state. I don't want to lose stuff! ack!

**Update** I backed up my VM and tried hitting that "discard" button and the result was a reboot of the VM. I then tried restoring to a snapshot, and none of my snapshots work! Is there anyway to fix this so I can run 7 but still have my old snapshots?

> The frame buffer layout of the current
>   display cannot be made to match the
>   frame buffer layout stored in the
>   snapshot.  The dimensions of the frame
>   buffer in the snapshot are: Max width
>   3200, Max height 1770, Max size
>   22659072.  The dimensions of the frame buffer on the current display are: Max
>   width 3200, Max height 1600, Max size
>   20512768. Error encountered while trying to restore the virtual machine
>   state from file "C:\Documents and
>   Settings\adam\My Documents\My Virtual
>   Machines\dev\Windows XP
>   Professional.vmss".

What do I do so I don't break things horribly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was screwed. I learned too late that you should only take snapshots when the guest OS is shut down :(